# Vue-Resource: How to get and show multiple arrays from JSON

Tags: vue-resource

I have a JSON from my API:

```
{"users":
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Adam"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Barry"}
],
"announcements":
[
    {"id":1,"content":"blah blah"},
    {"id":2,"content":"ya ya"}
]
}
```

How do I make vue-resource get those arrays and put them into `users` and `announcements` respectively, so that they can be looped in the view?

My script:

```
  export default {
    name: 'home',
    data: {
      users: [],
      announcements: []
    },
    methods: {
      fetchData () {
        this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000')
          .then(function (response) {
          // what do I put here to assign the response to users and announcements?
          })
      },
    },

    created: function () {
      this.fetchData()
    }
```

Comment: you might want to look into axios - i pretty standard for vue and makes these types of http requests a lot more friendly. I've never dealt with raw http requests like this, but with axios you can do essentially the same code and then just assign the response to an array.

Comment: As far as debugging, you could put 'console.dir(response);' and that should give you an idea in your browser console what the http request is giving you back and what you can assign.

Answer (score 0):

From Jayem's advice, I used Axios:

Install then reference axios

```
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$http = axios
```

Use Axios

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return { info: null, announcements: null, users: null }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$http
      .get('http://localhost:3000/')
      .then(response => {
        (this.info = response.data)
        console.log(response.data.announcements)
        console.log(response.data.users)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Add in View:

```
<div v-for="announcement in info.announcements">
 {{ announcement.content }}
</div>
<div v-for="user in info.users">
 {{ user.name }}
</div>
```